# Open new UI without closing the actual opened Ui

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I want is simply that when I press a button in the Actual Ui, opens a new Ui without closing the Actual Ui.

Here is a simple code that I did:

```
function shows(){      
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Actual Ui")
    .setHeight(3000).setWidth(1350);;

  var button = app.createButton('Button');
  var pan = app.createHorizontalPanel();

  pan.add(button)

  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("ps");
  button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(pan);

  app.add(pan);

   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // show the app
  doc.show(app)
}


function ps(e){    
  var apps = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(50).setWidth(200);
  apps.setTitle("New UI");

  var docsss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  docsss.show(apps);
  return apps
}
```

The code works perfectly but the fact that when I press the button it closes the Actual Ui and opens the new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like that, here is how it works, use the same app instance and change its content.

```
function shows(){      
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("common Ui")
    .setHeight(400).setWidth(1350);;

  var button = app.createButton('Button');
  var pan = app.createHorizontalPanel().setId('panelUi1');
  pan.add(app.createLabel(' first Ui'));

  pan.add(button)

  var clickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("ps");
  button.addClickHandler(clickHandler);
  clickHandler.addCallbackElement(pan);

  app.add(pan);

   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // show the app
  doc.show(app)
}


function ps(e){    
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('panelUi1').setVisible(false);
  app.add(app.createLabel('new Ui in the same app instance'));
  return app;
}
```